# How can I repair gnome-keyring to unlock my SSH keys automatically after login?

Tags: ssh, 15.10, 16.04, gnome-keyring

It looks like some recent package updates broke some functionality of gnome-keyring. When using SSH from the terminal it asks me for the password of my SSH private key. Previously the key was unlocked automatically when I logged in to Gnome.

Where can I find the log files of gnome-keyring to determine what went wrong?

gnome-keyring is still in the startup application launcher as usual with

```
/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=ssh
```

The problem happens on 2 Ubuntu 15.10 computers independently, so I assume some package update broke gnome-keyring. Do you know of an existing bug report or workaround to this issue?

Comment: My workaround for now is to invoke "ssh-add" from the terminal once and type in the password to my SSH key. SSH agent does not list any identities, so I assume gnome-keyring fails to add the unlocked key to SSH agent. I checked in seahorse and there it says that my SSH key is unlocked on Login, so that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem on my laptop.  The only workaround I've found so far is manually adding it once after I boot using "ssh-add" cli.